# Polymer- this object not available in function

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Using Polymer 1.0. I need the `setTimout` because there is a race condition with `<template is="dom-if" if="{{foo.bar}}">` and `<google-youtube>` being available when I run `this.$$('google-youtube');`. To keep the code clean, I like to have `startPlayer` player extracted out. But `this` object isn't available to it with `setTimeout(this.startPlayer, 1000);` calling it. How can I fix this? Since these functions are properties of `Object.create()` not  sure how.

```
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: "video-player",
      behaviors: [ 
        Polymer.PaperDialogBehavior,
        Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior
                 ],
      properties: {
        foo: Object,
        entryAnimation: {
          value: 'scale-up-animation'
        }
      },
      listeners: { 'iron-overlay-opened': 'enableElement',
                   'iron-overlay-closed': 'stopPlayer'
      },
      startPlayer: function() {
        youtubePlayer = this.$$('google-youtube');
        if (youtubePlayer.playbackstarted) {
         youtubePlayer.play();
        }
      },
      enableElement: function(e) {
        //this.playAnimation();
        this.foo = { bar: true};
        setTimeout(this.startPlayer, 1000);
      },
      stopPlayer: function(e) {
        youtubePlayer = this.$$('google-youtube');
        youtubePlayer.pause();
        youtubePlayer.seekTo(5);
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
setTimeout(this.startPlayer, 1000);
```

...with this:

```
setTimeout(this.startPlayer.bind(this), 1000);
```

If you aren't familiar with how `.bind()` works, here's a quick description from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The **bind()** method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Please note that `.bind()` isn't available in <=IE8, but it is pretty easy to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#polyfill).  If you're not a fan of polyfilling (and you need support in IE8), you could also just replace that line of code with the following:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    self.startPlayer();
}, 1000);
```